# Keep having to run export command on macbook to create Android Project with PhoneGap

Tags: linux, macos, bash

I am using phoneGap on my macbook but in order to get phoneGap to add the android project i keep having to run this command everytime i restart my macbook.  Is there a way i can update the machine permanently??

Here is the error i get:

```
MyUsers-MacBook-Pro:hello MyUser$ cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. 

/Users/MyUser/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.
at /Users/MyUser/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:85:29
at _rejected (/Users/MyUser/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
at /Users/MyUser/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
at Promise.when (/Users/MyUser/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/MyUser/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
at /Users/MyUser/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
at flush (/Users/MyUser/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/platform.js:244:30
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

And here is the command i run in order to fix it:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/MY/PATH/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/MY/PATH/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
```

Sorry but i am newish to the Macbook so please include detailed instructions and an explaination would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (Applications > Utilities > Terminal.app) and type.

```
file=$(ls -a .*profile)
echo "export PATH=${PATH}:/MY/PATH/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/MY/PATH/adt-bundle/sdk/tools" >> ${file-.bash_profile}
```

then press enter after each line.

Explanation: You need to add the line to the 'bash startup' file (Bash is the interpreter that acts on your commands when you launch the Terminal). There are three possible bash startup files: `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, and `.profile`. They are tested in that order. The `$(ls -a .*profile)` will find which one it is on your system. Note the use of `>>` to append to the file rather than overwriting it. The ${file-.bash_profile} part is necessary in case there is no preexisting bash startup file.

Comment: after typing file=$(ls -a .*profile), i get an error saying ls: .*profile: No such file or directory.  I am performing this command in my home directory...